# Why is Wordpress not working in other DNS

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting

I install Wordpress in Hostinger with Hostinger's DNS name, then it is working properly, but when I access with second DNS pointed to this site, the CSS on website is not working Although I check the source and the CSS link is not wrong. please help me! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I assume you’re trying to access your WordPress site with two different domain names, eg. *example.com* and *www.example.com*.

This usually causes problems with WordPress sites, due to the way the assets (CSS, Javascript, etc.) are referenced.

Choose one, eg. *www.example.com*, and redirect *example.com* to *www.example.com*.

Comment: I use cloudflare to point to my wordpress site... could you tell me how to solve it? thanks